# Changing stacked labels new line character to other than comma using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, python-parser, newline

Trying to execute some stacked labels with little bit of Python from the examples given here:
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/about-building-label-expressions.htm

The example for Python stacked labels uses a comma to denote the new line character but some of my fields have commas in them throwing it off.

Can the character be other than a comma?

Tried just using a blank space and it didn't accept that as an argument. I know semi colon is generally bad Python practice and tried it anyway (didn't work, wouldn't parse).

Suggestions?

Comment: Any sequence of characters will work in place of the `', '`, the example is just looking for where that occurs and replacing it with a newline in the label. It'll be syntactically valid provided that the field is a text type, but it **won't actually insert any newlines if that sequence of characters doesn't happen to exist in your field values**, which I suspect is your issue.  Maybe edit your post with an example of some field values, what you're trying to achieve, and the actual code you've tried

Comment: This was it exactly, commas were there but not correct sequence being registered (spaces in the coded sequence not in the text fields). Thank you